# XSL: select element value using XPath selector

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, css-selectors, transformation

I've the following XML scheme and I want to select the `Table>Row>Field with name = Amount`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <PermitDocument code="01312" id="1">
    <Field name="DocumentType">Certificate</Field>
    ...
    ...
    <Table name="Products">
      <Row>
        <Field name="Amount">1000</Field>
        ...
        ...
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Field name="Amount">3000</Field>
        ...
        ...
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </PermitDocument>
</Document>
```

I've the following code for transformation but nothing happens

```
<xsl:for-each select="Document/PermitDocument/Table[@name='Products']/Row">
    <xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='Amount']" />
    ...
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

C# code

```
XslTransform xs = new XslTransform();

try
{
  xs.Load("BCIS.xsl");
}
catch (XsltException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
  Console.ReadLine();
}

xs.Transform("BCIS.xml", "BCIS.html");
```

What is wrong with the syntax I used to achieve the goal?

Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
<Document>
    <PermitDocument code="01312" id="1">
        <Field name="DocumentType">Certificate</Field>
        <Table name="Products">
            <Row>
                <Field name="Amount">1000</Field>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Field name="Amount">3000</Field>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </PermitDocument>
</Document>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Document/PermitDocument/Table[@name='Products']/Row">
            <xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='Amount']" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
10003000
```

Comment: I use HTML templates instead xml and when I set `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>`, the output lost

Comment: @sultan, What is "HTML templates"?

Comment: Oh sorry, XSLT templates combined with html

Comment: If your code doesn't work then you need to show us your code.

Comment: Sorry guys, this stuff caused by `&nbsp;` symbols inside my template)